# Solution of a nonlinear equation depending on the parameter

Tags: equation-solving, asymptotics

I need to solve an equation

```
Solve[m + x*(-1 + 2*x - Log[2*Pi]) + (-1 + 2*m - 4*x)*x*Log[x] == 0, x]
```

It is not possible on a symbolic level. It would be ideal to find an asymptotic solution for `m -> Infinity`, i.e. `x = f(m)`. Of course, a numerical solution is possible for fixed values of the parameter m.

```
Do[Print[FindRoot[m + x*(-1 + 2*x - Log[2*Pi]) + (-1 + 2*m - 4*x)*x*Log[x] == 0, {x, m}]], {m, 10, 100, 10}]

(* {x->6.2906}
{x->12.0525}
{x->17.734}
{x->23.3683}
{x->28.9705}
{x->34.5488}
{x->40.1084}
{x->45.6528}
{x->51.1844}
{x->56.7052} *)
```

When we show it in the graph `x = f(m)`, it seems it could be `x = m/2 + ...`

```
ListPlot[Table[x /. FindRoot[m + x*(-1 + 2*x - Log[2*Pi]) + (-1 + 2*m - 4*x)*x*Log[x] == 0, {x, m}], {m, 1, 100}]]
```

[image: Graph x = f(m)]

But I would need at least one more term. I tried

```
AsymptoticSolve[m + x*(-1 + 2*x - Log[2*Pi]) + (-1 + 2*m - 4*x)*x*Log[x] == 0, {x}, {m, Infinity, 1}]
```

but without any result. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What does "one more term" mean here? Second order in $m$? You can try to fit your `FindRoot` solutions using e.g. `FindFit` perhaps?

Comment: If you think the solution should have a log component, you can try with `NonLinearModelFit`.

Comment: The expression will probably have the form m/2 + c*m/Log[m] + .... But I want Mathematica to compute this asymptotic expression, not get it from some numerical experiments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$m=\frac{-2 x^2+4 x^2 \log (x)+x+x \log (2 \pi )+x \log (x)}{2 x \log (x)+1}$$

```
Series[(x - 2 x^2 + x Log[2*Pi] + x Log[x] + 4 x^2 Log[x])/(1 + 2 x Log[x]), {x, Infinity, 1}]
```

$$m\sim \frac{x (2 \log (x)-1)}{\log (x)}+\frac{\log ^2(x)+\log (2 \pi ) \log (x)-\log (x)+1}{2 \log ^2(x)} + ...$$

Suppose

$$x\sim \frac{1}{2} m \left(\frac{c}{\log (m)}+1\right)$$
Now

```
Limit[Simplify[-m + ((-1 + 2 Log[x]) x)/Log[x] + (
  1 - Log[x] + Log[2 \[Pi]] Log[x] + Log[x]^2)/(2 Log[x]^2) /. 
 x -> m/2*(1 + c/Log[m])]/m*Log[m], m -> Infinity]

(* -1/2 + c *)
```

So
$$c=\frac{1}{2}$$
Similarly

```
Limit[Simplify[-m + ((-1 + 2 Log[x]) x)/Log[x] + (
 1 - Log[x] + Log[2 \[Pi]] Log[x] + Log[x]^2)/(2 Log[x]^2) /. 
x -> m/2*(1 + 1/(2*Log[m]) + d/Log[m]^2)]/(m/Log[m]^2), m -> Infinity]

(* -1/4 + d - Log[2]/2 *)
```

So
$$d=\frac{1}{4} (1+2 \log (2))$$
Final result
$$x\sim \frac{1}{2} m \left(1+\frac{1}{2 \log (m)}+\frac{1+2 \log (2)}{4 \log ^2(m)}\right)$$

**UPDATE**: The following code allows you to generate additional expressions:

```
terms = 4; Clear[f]; 
f[x_] := (x - 2 x^2 + x Log[2 \[Pi]] + x Log[x] + 4 x^2 Log[x])/(1 + 2 x Log[x]); 
xasy = 1; x0 = m/Limit[(f[x])/x, x -> Infinity]; 
Do[xasy = xasy + 1/Log[m]^j*c /. 
Solve[FullSimplify[
   Limit[Simplify[-m + f[x] /. x -> x0*(xasy + c/Log[m]^j)]/(m/
       Log[m]^j), m -> Infinity]] == 0][[1]]; 
Print[x0*xasy];, {j, 1, terms}];
```

[image: Expansion]

Comment: Nice solution, but I didn't  understand the assumption "xasy ~powerseries 1/Log[m]"

Answer (score 3):

Try the following. First, let us solve the equation with respect to m:

```
sl = Solve[
   m + x*(-1 + 2*x - Log[2*Pi]) + (-1 + 2*m - 4*x)*x*Log[x] == 0, 
   m][[1, 1]]

(*  m -> (x - 2 x^2 + x Log[2 \[Pi]] + x Log[x] + 4 x^2 Log[x])/(
 1 + 2 x Log[x])  *)
```

Now let us make a plot `x=x(m)` using the ParametricPlot.
At small x its is:

```
ParametricPlot[{m, x} /. sl, {x, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["m", Italic, 16], Style["x", Italic, 16]}]
```

[image]

while at large values of x the double logarithmic plot takes the following form (shown in blue):

```
Manipulate[Show[{
   ParametricPlot[{Log[m], Log[x]} /. sl, {x, 10, 100000}, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, 
    AxesLabel -> {Style["Log(m)", Italic, 16], 
      Style["Log(x)", Italic, 16]}],
   ParametricPlot[{Log[x^n] - \[Beta], Log[x]}, {x, 10, 100000}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red]
   }], {{n, 1}, 0.9, 1.1}, {{\[Beta], -0.642}, -1., 0}]
```

[image]

where the approximation

```
Log[m]==Log[x^n]-\[Beta]
```

with `n=1.` and `\[Beta] = -0.642` is shown in red color. One can see that the blue and the red lines closely overlap over four orders of magnitude, thus, giving an acceptable approximation.

If you need to get the solution at small `m` values you can take the list instead of the ParametricPlot and interpolatze it:

```
lst = Table[{m, x} /. sl, {x, 0.4, 1, 0.01}];
f = Interpolation[lst, InterpolationOrder -> 2];
```

Let us make sure that it is the same solution:

```
 Plot[f[m], {m, -0.4, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {Style["m", Italic, 16], Style["x", Italic, 16]}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Nice graphs, but that doesn't solve my problem. I am interested in the behavior of the function x(m) for m->Infinity, not for m->0.

Comment: Expanding in the solution `m=m(x)` I gave above `m(x)` in series around infinity we trivially get `2x==m`.

Comment: First term yes, but I need more terms. See my comment above. And I need a general method to expand it with Mathematica. Unfortunately, `InverseSeries` fails in this case.

Comment: There is no general method applicable to any equation. And I gave you a good approximation valid in the case of large values of m. I think that you did not formulate comprehensively enough, what do you need? Do you need to expand the solution in a  sort of series around infinity? "Sort of" because of the logarithmic terms.  Do you need an approximate solution correctly behaving itself in infinity? Or do you need something else. Anyway, I have never heard of any method that will be general in such a case.

Comment: This is a saddle point equation that I came across while solving another problem. Substitution of only the first term m/2 is insufficient, I needed more terms. After some effort, I found a solution myself. I think my method is quite general, I can generate more terms or apply it to another similar equation.

Answer (score 3):

First solve for `m`

```
solm = Solve[m + x*(-1 + 2*x - Log[2*Pi]) + (-1 + 2*m - 4*x)*x*Log[x] == 0, m][[1]]
```

and then

```
k = Limit[(m/.solm)/x, x -> Infinity]
```

so asymptotically as $m\to\infty$ we have $x(m) = 2 x$

Comment: This solve the first term `m/2`. Would there be more terms? So far is my conjecture `m/2 * (1 + 1/2/Log[m] + c/Log[m]^2 + ...)`.